# Bash: Checking for exit status of multi-pipe command chain

Tags: bash, pipe, snmp, exit-code, command-substitution

I have a problem checking whether a certain command in a multi-pipe command chain did throw an error. Usually this is not hard to check but neither `set -o pipefail` nor checking `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` works in my case. The setup is like this:

```
cmd="$snmpcmd $snmpargs $agent $oid | grep <grepoptions> for_stuff | cut -d',' f$fields | sed 's/ubstitute/some_other_stuff/g'"
```

Note-1: The command was tested thoroughly and works perfectly.

Now, I want to store the output of that command in an array called `procdata`. Thus, I did:

```
declare -a procdata
procdata=( $(eval $cmd) )
```

Note-2: `eval` is necessary because otherwise `$snmpcmd` throws up with an `invalid option -- <grepoption>` error which makes no sense because `<grepoption>` is not an `$snmpcmd` option obviously. At this stage I consider this a bug with `$snmpcmd` but that's another show...

If an error occurres, `procdata` will be empty. However, it might be empty for two different reasons: either because an error occurred while executing the `$snmpcmd` (e.g. timeout) or because `grep` couldn't find what it was looking for. The problem is, I need to be able to distinguish between these two cases and handle them separately.

Thus, `set -o pipefail` is not an option since it will propagate any error and I can't distinguish which part of the pipe failed. On the other hand `echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}` is always `0` after `procdata=( $(eval $cmd) )` even though I have many pipes!?. Yet if I execute the whole command directly at the prompt and call `echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}` immediately after, it returns the exit status of all the pipes correctly.

I know I could bind the err stream to stdout but I would have to use heuristic methods to check whether the elements in `procdata` are valid or error messages and I run the risk of getting false positives. I could also pipe stdout to `/dev/null` and capture only the error stream and check whether `${#procdata[@]} -eq 0`. But I'd have to repeat the call to get the actual data and the whole command is time costly (ca. 3-5s). I wouldn't want to call it twice. Or I could use a temporary file to write errors to but I'd rather do it without the overhead of creating/deleting files.

Any ideas how I can make this work in bash?

Thanks

P.S.:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.37(1)-release
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number of things here:

(1) When you say `eval $cmd` and attempt to get the exit values of the processes in the pipeline contained in the command `$cmd`,  `echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"` would contain **only** the exit status for `eval`. Instead of `eval`, you'd need to supply the complete command line.

(2) You need to get the `PIPESTATUS` while assigning the output of the pipeline to the variable.  Attempting to do that later wouldn't work.

---

As an example, you can say:

```
foo=$(command | grep something | command2; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]})"
```

This captures the output of the pipeline and the `PIPESTATUS` array into the variable `foo`.

You could get the command output into an array by saying:

```
result=($(head -n -1 <<< "$foo"))
```

and the `PIPESTATUS` array by saying

```
tail -1 <<< "$foo"
```

Comment: I had the same thought. Unfortunately it doesn't work either but I'm not sure why. I post the exact commands because I might not see the obvious:

Comment: `local cmdargs="-CHf , -m$mibs -v$snmpver -c$community $agent"; local procdatacmd="$tblcmd $cmdargs $proc_table "; procdatacmd+="| cut -d',' -f$fields | grep -w e <proc1> -e <proc2> | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *\|\"//g;s/ /,/g' ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}"`. Then I do: `declare -a procdata=( $(head -n -1 <<< $procdatacmd) )`. Output is empty ... just nothing. <proc1> and <proc2> are up and running on the agent. What the ...

Comment: @user3040975 You don't seem to be _running_ any command in the line above.

Comment: Right, sorry. But even `foo=$($procdatacmd); procdata=($(head -n -1 << $foo))` does not work: " /usr/bin/snmptable: invalid option -- '''". I have a "-x" switch to show the acutal command. Pasting and executing it on the prompt works flawlessly...

Comment: @user3040975 I assume that you have the command instead of a variable when you say `foo=$($procdatacmd);`.  To be even more clear, you need to put in the complete command instead of a variable in place of `$procdatacmd`.

Comment: Yeah I meant the variable. `temp=$($tblcmd $cmdargs $proc_table | cut -d',' -f$fields | $( get_pgreplist ) | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *\|\"/    /g;s/ /,/g' ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]})`. Now `procdata=( $(head -n -1 <<< $temp) )` does something, outputs nothing, although `procdata=( $(head <<< $temp) )` outputs the right values (line by line)?! I'm confused ...

Comment: @user3040975 You seem to be capturing the command output and exit status output into the same variable.  Simply say: `head -n -1 <<< "$temp"` and `tail -1 <<< "$temp"` first to see the result.  And please __quote__ the variables as indicated.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to capture both in `temp` as you did with `foo` and try to read it into `procdata` as you read it into `result`. Simply saying `head -n -1 <<< "$temp"` and `tail -1 <<< "$temp"` after the above `temp` assignment give the following errors: "head: cannot open '1 0 1 0 0 0' for reading: No such file or directory" and "tail: cannot open '1 0 1 0 0 0' for reading: No such file or directory" ...

Comment: @user3040975 You seem to be doing something wrong.  `1 0 1 0 0 0` indicate that the exit codes have been captured.  Simply say `echo "${temp}"` to see what it returns.

Comment: It works as you said. I don't know what I did wrong above. If I do as you said in your answer it works. Thanks for your time and effort. Just for completeness: `echo "${temp}"` outputs `10,httpd,runnable 64,nfsd,runnable 0 0 0 0 0 0`. Searching for `http` outputs `0 0 1 0 0 0` indicating failure to grep while a bogus IP will give me `1 0 1 0 0 0` as intended. Thanks again! Sadly I can't vote this up for lack of reputation ...